# How to put the last checkbox in useState in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing an application on React and I needed to add product checkboxes to the form. Everything works correctly except that the last action (marking or removing the checkbox) does not go to the server (the error is not in the server, I tested it separately). Here is the output of the checkboxes:

```
<Form.Group className="mb-3">
    <Form.Label>Товары</Form.Label>
        {prodsl.map((emp, index) =>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check
                    type='checkbox'
                    value={emp.id}
                    name='pp'
                    checked={checkedState[index]}
                    onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
                />
                {emp.name}
            </div>
        )}

</Form.Group>
```

And here is the handler (checkedState - an array of checkbox states):

```
const [prods, setProd] = useState([])
const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(555).fill(false)
);
const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
        index === position ? !item : item
    );
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
    let arr = []
    const updatedProd = checkedState.map((item, index) => {

        if (item) {
            arr = [...arr, index]
        }
    }
    );
    setProd(arr);

};
```

Submit form handler:

```
const newOrder = async () => {
    const response = await addOrder(prods, client, emp, d1, d2)
    stat++;
}
```

I tried to do a separate check before sending, I tried to call the function before sending it to a random checkbox so that this change would be the last and would not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Set states in react are async. It means that your values are not updated immediately after your setstate.

In order to fix the issue, you have 2 options.

1. Use the updatedCheckedState variable to set your prod:

```js
const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
        index === position ? !item : item
    );
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
    let arr = []
    const updatedProd = updatedCheckedState.map((item, index) => {
        if (item) {
            arr = [...arr, index]
        }
    }
    );
    setProd(arr);

};
```

2. Move your logic into useEffect:

```js
const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
        index === position ? !item : item
    );
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
};

useEffect(() => {
  let arr = []
  const updatedProd = checkedState.map((item, index) => {
    if (item) {
      arr = [...arr, index]
    }
  });
  setProd(arr);
}, [checkedState]);
```

**And as a suggestion, use `arr.push(index)` instead of `arr = [...arr, index];`**